# What does 念不過你 mean?

Tags: meaning

The full sentence containing this phrase is 我想他念不過你.
From DeFrancis' Beginning Chinese Reader p. 185 – Lesson 19, Exercise 5, Item 12

Comment: I flipped through this book and the contents look very outdated, like early texts when written vernacular Chinese was not standardized. Since written vernacular Chinese is very young, it went through radical changes these years. I don't think it's a good textbook for beginners.

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing the full context, 念 here seems to be short for 念書 (study)

我想他(念書)念不過你 = 我覺得他在學習上比不過你  = I think he can't beat you in studying

Meaning you study harder, smarter, learn more, and get better grades than him